# Forward TCP packets by destination and port number

Tags: proxy, tcp

Is there any way to forward only TCP packets heading to destination XYZ and port number NN to 127.0.0.1 port number 9150 ?

I'm on Windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might work (on Windows 7+, [with IPv6 stack installed even if it's IPv4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555744)):

```
netsh interface portproxy 
    add v4tov4 listenport=NN listenaddress=XYZ
    connectport=9150 connectaddress=127.0.0.1
```

If it does not (I'm not sure whether listenaddress needs to be one of the registered interfaces), you might need to intercept the whole traffic to port NN; this will almost certainly work in general, but it's not exactly what you asked for, and it will not work if you want to intercept port NN but *not*, say, port NN+1.

```
netsh interface portproxy 
    add v4tov4 listenport=NN listenaddress=0.0.0.0
    connectport=9150 connectaddress=127.0.0.1
```

You could also try [Rouvali's service](http://www.rouvali.com/?page_id=33). It seems more flexible, but is apparently deprecated in favour of `netsh` itself.

Comment: Not working! Would you please take a look at this post to find more details : https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/79908/hide-email-senders-ip-using-tor